# Appending to non existing element

Tags: php

Can you please explain how does this code work and why does it work:

```php
$a = [];

$a[] += '1';

var_dump($a);
```

I understand that `$a[]` created a new element in an array. Whereas `+=` is supposed to merge two arrays. Yet I expected this code to throw and error.

This code produces the same result:

```php
$a = [];

$a[] .= '1';

var_dump($a);
```

Comment: `+=` is more normally adding to a numeric value.

Comment: What leads you to believe the first example merges two arrays? The 2 examples do not produce the same result. The first one creates an array with an integer, 1, as the only value. The 2nd one creates an array with a string that happens to contain 1. Similar but certainly not the same.